# Reed-Solomon full-rank parity-check matrix

Tags: coding-theory

I start to learn about Reed-Solomon code and I find this question but have hard time to solve it -$$$$ Let $\alpha \in F_{2^m}$ be a primitive element. Let $C_{BCH}$ be a code over $F_2$ of length $n = 2^m- 1$ with a parity-check matrix, $H_{BCH} = $

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \alpha & \alpha^2 & ... & \alpha^{n-1}\\
1 & \alpha^3 & \alpha^6 &... & \alpha^{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}

Let $C_{RS}$ be a conventional Reed-Solomon code over $F_{2^m}$ with parameters [N, K, D], $N = n = 2^m-1$, such that
$$C_{BCH} = C_{RS} \cap F^N_2 $$

Write a full-rank parity-check matrix for $C_{RS}$ if we know that D = 5 and $\alpha^3$ is a root of $C_{RS}$.

Comment: Since this is essentially homework, I will only give hints. The minimum distance of the binary BCH code is also $5$, and $\alpha^2$ and $\alpha^4$ (which are conjugates of $\alpha$) also are roots of the generator polynomial of $C_{\text{BCH}}$.  Therefore, $C_{\text{RS}}$ is a $[2^n-1,2^n-5,5]$ RS code with generator polynomial $(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^2)(x-\alpha^3)(x-\alpha^4)$.